# Логическая ошибка в условии

Tags: php

Добрый день! Простите за глупый вопрос возможно, но у меня возникла ошибка странная. Делаю условия проверки на пустоту полей, связываю их оператором && и браузер выдает такую ошибку:

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_BOOLEAN_AND in S:\home\localhost\www\web_shop\checkout.php on line 33

И ругается на этой строке:

```
if (!empty($_POST[fio])) && (!empty($_POST[adress])) && (!empty($_POST[city])) && (!empty($_POST[country])) && (!empty($_POST[email])) && (!empty($_POST[telephone]))
```

В чем хитрость тут? Много программировал сегодня, уже глаза замылились, не вижу очевидного...

Comment: проверка комментирования в закрытый вопрос.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
if (!empty($_POST[fio])) && (!empty($_POST[adress])) && (!empty($_POST[city])) && (!empty($_POST[country])) && (!empty($_POST[email])) && (!empty($_POST[telephone]))
```

Проблема со скобками. Замените на:

```
    if ( !empty($_POST[fio]) && !empty($_POST[adress]) && !empty($_POST[city]) && !empty($_POST[country]) && !empty($_POST[email]) && !empty($_POST[telephone]) )
```

Comment: спасибо) за ответ

Answer (score 2):

По-моему присутствуют лишние скобки.

```
if (!empty($_POST[fio]))
```

Вот даже в первом условии вы сразу закрыли if.

Comment: спасибо) за ответ